# What is the previous password restriction setting for Azure cloud accounts?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-domain-services

When looking at the documentation for Azure AD password policy, I do not see any restriction on previous password history usage with the exception that it cannot be the last password.  Is it possible to set a password policy that does not allow the last 15 passwords to be used when changing passwords in Azure?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts

FYI - We are not using on-premise domain/syncing, but we are leveraging Azure Active Directory Domain Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorry to tell you that it's impossible to change the password policy on using old password in azure ad according to [ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/set-password-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide#prevent-last-password-from-being-used-again). It's said clearly that creating custom password policy is only effective for on-premises ad.

[image]